# How to send an object over network

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to send an object from a client to a server, but sockets only let you send bytes.  How do I convert a custom object to bytes in Python 3.5 so I can send it via the socket?

Comment: With **`pickle`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serialize the object using `pickle`, which will convert it to `bytes` and allow you to send it.  You can read up on how to use `pickle` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: When I try to do that I get TypeError: can't pickle CompiledFFI objects

Comment: Not all objects can be pickled, like compiled objects (like it sounds like you've got).  What type of object are you trying to send?  Does the whole object need to be sent, or can you send data about its state only (which isn't precompiled) and send that instead?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you are trying to send over the webs, if it is just some basic `dict` or `list` of basic types you could serialize it to `json`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

If you really want to serialize entire python class then use already mentioned `pickle`, although it can be dangerous, see [here](https://www.kevinlondon.com/2015/08/15/dangerous-python-functions-pt2.html).

And remember to **NOT** execute anything deserialized which came from the internet.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to serialize your object, which can be done with the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) library.